# C++ UDP recvfrom WSAGetLastError 10014

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp

This may be a duplicate question but I have read the other threads and solutions and found nothing missing in the code. Something is there which I am not able to figure out.

Below is the code for a UDP server

```
#pragma once
#pragma comment( linker, "/defaultlib:ws2_32.lib" )

#include <io.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
#define REQUEST_PORT 0x7070
#define TIMEOUT_USEC 300000         
#define MAX_RETRIES 3           
int port=REQUEST_PORT;
//socket data types
SOCKET serverSocket;
SOCKET cs;
SOCKADDR_IN serverSocketAddr; 
SOCKADDR_IN clientSocketAddr; 
int senderAddrSize = sizeof (clientSocketAddr);
char *buffer;
char localhost[21];
HOSTENT *hp;

int main(void)
{
    try
    {
        initializeSockets();
    }
    catch(char* str)
    {
        LPTSTR Error = 0;
        if(FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,NULL,WSAGetLastError() | GetLastError(),0,(LPTSTR)&Error,0,NULL) == 0)
        {
            cout<<str<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cerr<<Error<<endl;
        }
        LocalFree(Error);
    }
    return 0;
}
void initializeSockets()
{
    try
    {
        WSADATA wsadata;
        if (WSAStartup(0x0202,&wsadata)!=0)
        {
            throw "Error in starting WSAStartup()";
        }
        else
        {
            buffer="WSAStartup was suuccessful\n";
        }
        gethostname(localhost,20);
        cout<<"hostname: "<<localhost<< endl;
        if((hp=gethostbyname(localhost)) == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Cannot get local host info."
                << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        if((serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0))==INVALID_SOCKET) 
            throw "can't initialize socket";
        serverSocketAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverSocketAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
        serverSocketAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        if (::bind(serverSocket,(LPSOCKADDR)&serverSocketAddr,sizeof(serverSocketAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            throw "can't bind the socket";
        if(recvfrom(serverSocket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,(SOCKADDR *)&clientSocketAddr, &senderAddrSize)==SOCKET_ERROR)
                throw "Error";

    }
    catch(char* str)
    { 
        LPTSTR Error = 0;
        if(FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,NULL,WSAGetLastError() | GetLastError(),0,(LPTSTR)&Error,0,NULL) == 0)
        {
            cout<<str<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cerr<<Error<<endl;
        }
        LocalFree(Error);
    }
}
```

on recvfrom I am getting the WSAError 10014: The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument of a call.

I tried setting the last two parameters to NULL, it works fine then, which means error is in those two pointer variables. But I have properly casted the sockaddr_in to sockaddr and also initialized the length with the sizeof sockaddr. Still getting the error. Don't know what is missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120.aspx) for `recvfrom()` is very clear on what causes 10014 (WSAEFAULT):

> WSAEFAULT
>   **The buffer pointed to by the `buf` or `from` parameters are not in the user address space**, or the `fromlen` parameter is too small to accommodate the source address of the peer address.

You are assigning a string literal to the `buffer` that you pass to `recvfrom()`:

```
buffer="WSAStartup was suuccessful\n";
```

A string literal resides in read-only memory that `recvfrom()` cannot write to.

Also, `buffer` is declared as `char*`, so using `sizeof(buffer)` is wrong.

You need to allocate writable memory for `buffer`, and get rid of the useless assignment, eg:

```
char buffer[65535];
```

Then `sizeof(buffer)` will be meaningful.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I think I just ignored the part in bold of WSAEFAULT and just focused on the struct length part. Will be more careful and observant next time.